# Want to select a img using class and data-value using jquery multiple selector

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to select a img from batch of imgs using jquery multiple selector.

```
$('.selected-yes')
```

Return this

```
[img src=​"" class=​"partSelect selected-yes" style=​"margin-top:​ 5px;​ width:​ 50px;​ height:​ 50px;​" data-matvalue=​"P1_M1" data-partvalue=​"P1">, 
img src=​"" class=​"partSelect selected-yes" style=​"margin-top:​ 5px;​ width:​ 50px;​ height:​ 50px;​" data-matvalue=​"P2_M1" data-partvalue=​"P2", 
<img src=​"/​images/​septWolvesUI/​Mats/​P3_M1.jpg" class=​"partSelect selected-yes" style=​"margin-top:​ 5px;​ width:​ 50px;​ height:​ 50px;​" data-matvalue=​"P3_M1" data-partvalue=​"P3">​, 
img src=​"" class=​"partSelect selected-yes" style=​"margin-top:​ 5px;​ width:​ 50px;​ height:​ 50px;​" data-matvalue=​"P4_M1" data-partvalue=​"P4">, 
<img src=​"" class=​"partSelect selected-yes" style=​"margin-top:​ 5px;​ width:​ 50px;​ height:​ 50px;​" data-matvalue=​"P5_M1" data-partvalue=​"P5">​, 
img src=​"/​images/​septWolvesUI/​Mats/​P6_M1.jpg" class=​"partSelect selected-yes" style=​"margin-top:​ 5px;​ width:​ 50px;​ height:​ 50px;​" data-matvalue=​"P6_M1" data-partvalue=​"P6"> ]
```

I want to select an img which have class 'selected-yes' and 'data-partvalue="P1"'. I tried many thing but can't find the rite way

my tries:

```
$('.selected-yes[partvalue='P1']')
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
$('.selected-yes[data-partvalue='P1']')
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Please Help me to select a single `img` with class `'selected-yes'` and `'data-partvalue="P1"'`.

Comment: You can not use single quotes at both places.

try `$('.selected-yes[partvalue="P1"]')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is you are using singlequotes in both places and getting syntax error.

Try this:

```
$('.selected-yes[partvalue="P1"]')
```

Your mistake is in here:

```
$('.selected-yes[partvalue='P1']') is treated as separate statements
                           ^  ^
```

**NOTE:** You should use a good editor, notepad would not highlight this but you would easily be able to detect it using `sublime` or `eclipse` or any other **IDE**